# Opencv: Why does the file size change when I read and write an image without making any changes?

Tags: python, opencv, glob, tiff, filesize

I have a list of (.TIFF) files which I am renaming and saving in the same format.
I am using cv2 module to do this.

```
import cv2
import os
import glob

os.chdir('C:/99_Temp/')

for file in glob.glob("*.tiff"):
   f = os.path.splitext(file)
   time_val = f[0][:2]
   a1 = cv2.imread(file)
   cv2.imwrite(time_val+'.tiff',a1)
```

Why are the file sizes reduced from the original TIFF file? I haven't done any processing and visually the images look the same. But I am wondering, why the difference?

[image]

Comment: Wild guess: Different implementations/versions/parameters for the tiff encoding? How was the original file generated? And, if you read and write the second image once again, do the second and third image have the same size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There could be many explanations of why the size of a TIFF file changes. Here are a few:

- one file may be RGB with 3 bytes of red, green and blue per pixel, while another encoder may see that the file has fewer than 256 colours and decide to write a single byte of palette index per pixel (and store the 256 colours in a separate palette) rather than 3 bytes of RGB.
- one file may be 8-bit, the other may be 1-bit (bi-level), 16 bit, 32-bit or 64-bit.
- the files may have different compression - varying through none, to LZW, RLE or more recently JPEG.
- one coder may have written IPTC or other metadata, whilst the other discarded it.
- one coder may have included a low resolution preview, the other not.

---

In order to check, you could use `exiftool` which is *just* a Perl script and simple and small to install:

```
exiftool image.tif
```

**Sample Output**

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.11
File Name                       : image.tif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 91 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:11:28 09:38:03+00:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:12:05 13:15:15+00:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:12:05 13:15:10+00:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 784
Image Height                    : 1466
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Compression                     : LZW
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 827 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Samples Per Pixel               : 1
Rows Per Strip                  : 10
Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 642 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Predictor                       : Horizontal differencing
Image Size                      : 784x1466
Megapixels                      : 1.1
```

---

Or `tiffinfo` which comes with `libtiff` and is also pretty small and easy to install:

```
tiffinfo image.tif
```

**Sample Output**

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x16894 (92308)
  Image Width: 784 Image Length: 1466
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: LZW
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 10
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Predictor: horizontal differencing 2 (0x2)
```

---

Or **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows - but is quite a large install:

```
magick identify -verbose image.tif
```

**Sample Output**

```
Image: image.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 784x1466+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: Gray
  Type: Grayscale
  Endianess: LSB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Gray: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 1149344
    Gray:
  ...
  ...
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 784x1466+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2018-12-05T13:15:10+00:00
    date:modify: 2018-11-28T09:38:03+00:00
    signature: 5f9afdc8efd4757daa7f6bdba105f6ae149833c1c8103dd544f0073bb302069d
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: min-is-black
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 10
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 93622B
  Number pixels: 1.14934M
  Pixels per second: 114.935MP
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.009
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-14 Q16 x86_64 2018-11-16 https://imagemagick.org
```